# "Loop function to find the number of null value in each column in a data frame R"

Tags: r

Need help for the below problem.

How to use loop function to find the number of 'Null' values in each column for a data frame.

Thanks

Example: `df<-data.frame(name=c("Patrik","Tom","Harry","Bose"),
                 Age=c(45,NA,54,34),
               Location=c("NA","CA",NA,"IR"))`

Comment: Could you define `NULL`? Is NULL NULL or NA? If there's an image in the post that describes that, sorry I can't see it. Maybe post it as code?

Comment: You mean `NA`, I assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count values defined as `NA` by column.

```
colSums(is.na(df))
    # name      Age Location 
    #    0        1        1
```

To include the string `"NA"` as well:

```
colSums(is.na(df) | df == "NA")
    # name      Age Location 
    #    0        1        2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NULL, NA, 4, 6)
```

Then typing c will output: `[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5 NA  4  6`

As you can see, NULL is nonexistant, but NA is maybe what you're after? 
In that case you can simply do `is.na(c)` which will output: `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`.

P.S. TRUE / FALSE behaves like 1 / 0, so `sum(is.na(c))` is 1.

Comment: thanks, but if we have a dataframe with more than one column then how to get the details at once.

Comment: You can get the number of NAs like @sindri_baldur specified. 
You can also get which entry is specified as NA with fx `sapply(c, is.na)`